# extracting file name into appended data in R

Tags: r, loops

I am merging multiple files in folder , but I also like to bind the a portion of the file name to each append record  eg file name is 181523_chance_day_speed.. 181523 is subject id and I want a new column that will contain subject id ..

Below is what I have so far to merge files

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)

combined_csv <-  ldply(coo.files, read_csv)
```

Comment: Two comments: (1) Since `readr > 2.0.0`, `readr::read_csv` can take a list of files which are being read and automatically merged. No need to wrap this in a loop anymore. (2) I advise against using `plyr` (to avoid potential future conflicts with `dplyr`). Better to use e.g. `purrr`'s `map*_*` functions, which work smoothly with functions from the other higher-level `tidyverse` packages.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the id of the file name, you can use :

```
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract(string = "181523_chance_day_speed.csv", pattern = "\\d{6}")

"181523"
```